# Настройка Jquery Image Zoom Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, адаптивная-верстка, интернет-магазин

имеется интернет-магазин "товаров интимного здоровья" на WP. писал не я, мне достались лишь доработки.
итак, при работе через мобильные устройства у нас работает адаптивная верстка - просто медиа-запросами, как я понимаю, красивенько(относительно) всё сжимается под размеры дисплея уст-ва.
зайдя в карточку товарА, вверху мы видим само изображение, по которому нельзя скроллить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это, как выяснилось, достигается посредством Jquery Image Zoom Plugin.
теперь вопрос - как быть?
как настроить этот момент? ведь происходит, видимо, перехват события тапа по дисплею или что?

Comment: Инициализируйте этот плагин только на устройствах с шириной больше, например, 600 пикселей по ширине.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: при фокусе на картинке уменьшать и увеличивать её. Достигается с помощью плагинов Mousewheel, imgViewer и ваш Jquery Image Zoom Plugin. Готовое решение можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-In-Out-With-Mousewheel-imgViewer.html):

Вариант 2: с помощь css подогнать картинки.

```css
.img-container {
  width:200px; 
  height:200px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.img-container img {
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto; 
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://cdn.riastatic.com/photosnew/auto/photo/infiniti_qx70__160250419b.jpg" >

    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img  src="http://euroavto.in/journalist/images/news/210/icon/d_22.jpg" />
    </div>
```